# Online GIS app that allows users to log points

Tags: web-mapping, online, free-software

I am developing a website for a dolphin volunteer group, on this website they want a system to let volunteers and the public log sightings against a map and add some comments.

I have made a system using the google maps API and a database, which does the job but will need more work. I was just wondering if there is a web based, simple GIS framework that would do the same thing?

They are just using it to gather data for research purposes, so something open-source or freely useable for this purpose would be what we are after.

Comment: Why don't you read over our [highly voted threads](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-mapping?sort=votes&pageSize=30) on this subject?